# stdoutput is empty in ideone

Tags: c, string, gcc

This code works fine in **windows or codechef ide** but in ideone it doesn't shows any output--- *Standard output is empty*. I have tried taking return value of scanf but nothing changed.
my input is

```
hello world
hello
```

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int strend(char[], char[]);
int main()
{
    //program to return 1 if string2 matches with end of string1
    char array_1[100] ;
    char array_2[100] ;
    scanf("%[^\n]%*c",array_1);
    scanf("%[^\n]%*c",array_2);
    printf("%d", strend(array_1, array_2));
    return 0;
}
int strend(char a[], char b[])
{
    int length_a = strlen(a);
    int length_b = strlen(b);
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = length_b, j = length_a; i > 0; i--, j--)
    {
        if (a[j - 1] == b[i - 1])
        {
            count++;
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }
        if (count == length_b)
            return 1;
    }
    
}
```

Comment: `printf("...\n", ...);` ie, print **lines**.

Comment: thx it worked but previous i tried outputing printing empty string but it wasn't giving anything

Comment: Re “i tried outputing printing empty string but it wasn't giving anything”: What output did you expect printing an empty string to produce?

Comment: no no the answer he gave me was to print a new line but i tried printing space and few other things but nothing worked